# '_ ??' is not convertible to '()' with NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, string, swift, uilabel

I've to say that i'm pretty new to Swift and i'm stuck in setting a `NSMutableAttributedString` in a `UILabel`.

```
var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString("random string for this example")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(1, 3))
tweetTextLabel?.text = attributedString
```

The last line gives to me: `'_ ??' is not convertible to '()'` so I can't even compile.

I tried also with:

```
tweetTextLabel?.text = attributedString.string
```

but in this way I lose the color attribute

Comment: `tweetTextLabel?.attributedText = attributedString`

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't notice that method in UILabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set to the `attributedText` property of the `UILabel`, like:

```
tweetTextLabel?.attributedText = attributedString
```